# How can I save run commands so that the user can just click play on docker desktop?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to deploy a console app for windows and mac via docker, the user will have to mount a folder via the -v option.

To avoid running a command line each time the user wants to start the app, I would like to save the config so that he can just click play on docker desktop and have the app run with the mounted drive.

Is it possible?

Comment: I also found this command --restart unless-stopped any experience with it?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: thank you it seems the way to go

Comment: I'm not saying it's the way to go, just giving an answer to your above comment. Your question is actually (to my eyes at least) to wide to be clearly answered. My 2 cent: I would try to run the "thing" with `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is useful but how about just create a script when clicked on runs those commands you don't want the user to run each time.

Comment: yes I was thinking about that, I also found this command --restart unless-stopped any experience with it?